# AWS Pinpoint/Ionic - "Resource not found" error when trying to send push through CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, cordova, ionic-framework, push-notification

I am new at programming with AWS services, so some fundamental things are pretty hard for me. Recently, I was asked to develop an app that used Amazon Pinpoint to send push notifications, as a test for considering future implementations.

As you can see in another question I posted in here ([Amazon Pinpoint and Ionic - Push notifications not working when app is in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51179186/amazon-pinpoint-and-ionic-push-notifications-not-working-when-app-is-in-backgr)), I was having trouble trying to send push notifications to users when my app is running in the background. The app was developed using Ionic by following [these steps](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/blogs/mobile/push-notifications-with-ionic-and-amazon-pinpoint/).

When I was almost giving up, I decided to try sending the pushes directly through **Firebase**, and it finally worked. Some research took me to [this question](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=856986#856986), in which another user described the problem as only happening in AWS Console, so the solution would be to use CLI. After searching a little about it, I found [this tutorial about how to sending pinpoint messages to users using CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/pinpoint/send-messages.html), that seems to be what I wanted. Combining it with [this documentation about phonegap plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/PAYLOAD.md), I was able to generate a JSON I thought could be a solution:

```
{
    "ApplicationId":"io.ionic.starter",
    "MessageRequest":{
        "Addresses": {
            "": {
                "BodyOverride": "",
                "ChannelType": "GCM",
                "Context": {
                    "": ""
                },
                "RawContent": "",
                "Substitutions": {},
                "TitleOverride": ""
            }
        },
        "Context": {
            "": ""
        },
        "Endpoints": {"us-east-1": {
            "BodyOverride": "",
            "Context": {},
            "RawContent": "",
            "Substitutions": {},
            "TitleOverride": ""
          }
        },
        "MessageConfiguration": {

            "GCMMessage": {
                "Action": "OPEN_APP",
                "Body": "string",
                "CollapseKey": "",
                "Data": {
                    "": ""
                },
                "IconReference": "",
                "ImageIconUrl": "",
                "ImageUrl": "",
                "Priority": "High",
                "RawContent": "{\"data\":{\"title\":\"sometitle\",\"body\":\"somebody\",\"url\":\"insertyourlinkhere.com\"}}",
                "RestrictedPackageName": "",
                "SilentPush": false,
                "SmallImageIconUrl": "",
                "Sound": "string",
                "Substitutions": {},
                "TimeToLive": 123,
                "Title": "",
                "Url": ""
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when I executed it in cmd with `aws pinpoint send-messages --color on --region us-east-1 --cli-input-json file://test.json`, I got the response `An error occurred (NotFoundException) when calling the SendMessages operation: Resource not found`.

I believe I didn't write the JSON file correctly, since it's my first time doing this. So please, if any of you know what I am doing wrong, no mattering which step I misunderstood, I would appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2):

"Endpoints" field in the Message request deals with the endpoint id (the identifier associated with an end user device while registering to pinpoint and not the region.)

In case if you haven't registered any endpoints with Pinpoint, you can use the "Addresses" field. After registering the GCM Channel in Amazon Pinpoint, you can get the GCM device token from your device and specify it here.

Here is a sample for sending direct messages using Amazon Pinpoint  Note: The example deals with sending SMS message. You should have registered a SMS channel first and created an endpoint with the endpoint id as "test-endpoint1". Otherwise, you can use the "Addresses" field instead of "Endpoints" field.

```
 aws pinpoint send-messages --application-id $APP_ID --message-request '{"MessageConfiguration": {"SMSMessage":{"Body":"hi hello"}},"Endpoints": {"test-endpoint1": {}}}
```

**Also Note**: ApplicationId is generated by Pinpoint. When you visit the Pinpoint console and choose your application, the URL will be of the format

```
https://console.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/home/?region=us-east-1#/apps/someverybigstringhere/
```

Here "someverybigstringhere" is the ApplicationId and not the name you give for your project.